# Incrementing Count +1 on another Worksheet

Tags: excel, formula, countif, vba

I have a spreadsheet with 2 worksheets in it. In the first worksheet, it is a task list which has a couple columns such as phone number, location, etc. However, it has  rows going down which corresponds to different types of materials [steel, sugar, metal and more (and a lot these repeat too)]. These materials are in Column D; there a total of 1102 rows. The column I am interested is in Column I. In this column, I have used conditional formatting to validate the cells in the columns with the following rules: If 1 is inserted, the cell is gray. If 2 is inserted, the cell turns yellow. If 3 is inserted, the cell turns green (the reason it's like this is because Column I is a "status" column as I've named it which will allow me to keep track if the status is completed or not).

Then, we move over to the second worksheet which I am using to track different metrics. What I am trying to do is, I have a column C in worksheet 2 which is all my "completed" items. Hence, anytime a 3 (green) was inserted into the Column I on the first worksheet, I want it to increment the count automatically by +1 here in the second worksheet with the associated material. However, there might be 10 different entries of STEEL for instance that are green (3). So in the second worksheet, for STEEL it should list 10 completed.

Quick Ex:

```
MATERIALS STATUS
STEEL 3 [would be green]
STEEL 3 [would be green]
SUGAR 3 [would be green]

So in worksheet 2:
MATERIALS COMPLETED
STEEL 2 [two here because it found that 2 steel were marked 3/green]
SUGAR 1
```

I hope this makes sense. I am trying to do more conditional formatting on the second worksheet to create my own formula to do this, but for some reason, I am thinking it has to be done with a macro. Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you very much.

P.S.
I've been trying to use this INDIRECT formula and I think this may also be able to do it. But I can't figure out the formula. I know the logic:

IF COLUMN I in WORKSHEET 1 contains 3, then increment +1 in COLUMN C in WORKSHEET 2.

However, I don't know how to incorporate the rows into this and group together the count if it's 10 STEELS for instance.

Comment: You could try using the COUNTIFS function - it allows you to count the number of cells that meet specific criteria... for example, you could check to see if the value in column I is 3, while the value in column A (or whichever) is STEEL, then it would automatically (dynamically) count the number of cells meeting both criteria.

Comment: I believe a COUNTIF can also work but I'm having trouble with that formula. 

`=COUNTIF('Worksheet1 Where'!I:I,"=3")`

This seems to be partially working. For any values of 3 in worksheet 1 in column I, it is incrementing +3 in the second worksheet but ONLY in C1.
It needs to be doing only +1 and it should be doing it based on each material. This is a weird +3 increment which just sits in C1. Any tips?

Comment: You came close to what I intended, but you missed slightly.  I mentioned the [COUNTIFS](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countifs-function-HA010047494.aspx) function - notice the 'S' on the end.  This allows for extra conditions.  For example, on C2 on your second worksheet (assuming C2 corresponds to STEEL, and assuming the item name is in column A on the first sheet, and that the first sheet is named 'Sheet1'), you could try something like `COUNTIFS(Sheet1!I:I,"=3",Sheet1!A:A,"=STEEL")`.  The intended effect would be to count the number of times with both "=3" AND "=STEEL".

Comment: Ah, I see. I will give this a try and play around with the COUNTIFS. But you are also suggesting that I will have to create a different formula for each material in the second worksheet (basically just changing the name from =STEEL to the next material?)

Comment: @pnuts had it right - I didn't see that you mentioned column D (so his D:D is correct).  For the "different formula" - you're putting this formula in column C on your second sheet.  Assuming Column B contains the item name (i.e. STEEL), then you could do it like so in row 2: `COUNTIFS(Sheet1!I:I, "=3", Sheet1!D:D, =B2)`, then you could just copy this same formula down, and the B2 reference would automatically update to the different materials.

Comment: Awesome!! I got it guys. Thanks so much.

Comment: Maybe I should have put that in an answer so you can accept it... ;)

Comment: @pnuts - right again... leave off the '=' on `=b2` - so make it just `b2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments on the question itself, here is a solution.  This particular formula makes the following assumptions:

- The item name (STEEL, etc.) is in column D on the first sheet (mentioned in the question)
- The item's count (=2, =3, etc.) is on column I of the first sheet (also specified in the question)
- The first sheet is called 'Sheet1'
- The item name is in column B on the second sheet
- This particular formula is placed in cell C2 on the second sheet

`=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!I:I, "=3", Sheet1!D:D, B2)`

To explain briefly how it works - it's testing for two conditions: the "=3" in column I (as needed per the question), and the item name on Sheet2 matching the item name on Sheet1 (which does the grouping by item name, as requested).  This formula can then be copied using Auto-Fill to as many rows (still in column C on the second sheet) as needed.

Comment: There you go. Gave you the answer! :D Hehe. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the well-written, thought-out question, and for the clarification of requirements when requested.